Insidious leaking windows
I have subfloor rot due to leaking windows. Seems the water comes down the inside of the outerwall hits the plate and then soaks the subfloor. Know enough to replace the subfloor, but unsure how to stop the leak. Windows are an integrated double glazed unit. The house is stucco, with the stucco coming right up to the windows .

Some pictures of the outside of the windows showing the edge of window and stucco will help.  Usually should be some sealer between the window and stucco.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Window or roof leaks are sometimes hard to track down.  The only guarantee is that the source of the leak is above where you're seeing it.  Could be where the stucco meets the window, it could be higher up and the leak is flowing inside your wall somewhere down to where you can see it.  The first step is to carefully inspect the whole outside of the window perimeter for any gaps and seal those.  Then look higher all the way to the top of the structure to confirm there are no gaps or opportunities for water intrusion higher up.
